# Term for sum of matrix multiplications (more specifically contractions)

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, operator-theory

What is the general term for the following operation on a matrix $\rho$
$$
f(\rho) = \sum_i X_i \rho X_i^\dagger
$$

Ideally there is a term for any general set of {$X_i$} and $\rho$. I know from [Choi's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choi%27s_theorem_on_completely_positive_maps) that you could describe this sum (for a restricted set of $\rho$s and ${X_i}$) as a Completely Postive (CP) map, but I am trying to find out what the most general name of such an operation is.

I would like to say the sentence:
Choi's Theorem states that any CP map can be written as a "(insert math term here)"